# How to Connect Salesforce using R?

Tags: r, api, connection, salesforce

**I am getting 500 status. Can you anyone help me on this please**

I am trying to connect Salesforce using R when i try perform the login operation. I am not successful, can you please look into this code and correct me where i am missing.

```
library(RCurl)
library(httr)

  body1 = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Body>
  <login xmlns="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com">
  <username>xxxxxx.Test@xxxxxx.com.xxxxxxx</username>
  <password>xxxxxxxxxxxx</password>
  </login>
  </s:Body>
  </s:Envelope>'

x <- httr::POST(url = "https://test.salesforce.com/services/Soap/48.0", body = body1, content_type("text/xml;charset=UTF-8"),SOAPAction = "login")
x$status_code
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for answering the questions. After several tries, I understood there was some issue in the headers. I fixed the headers and its now working great. I am able to perform a query in Salesforce without any issues. I have posted my complete code here so anyone can make use for it. I am not an expert in this but still managed with this code.

```
#######Required Packages
library(RCurl)
library(httr)
library(XML)
library(jsonlite)
library(xml2)
library(magrittr)
library(randomNames)
library(rlang)
library(generator)
library(stringr)
require(data.table)

body1 = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>\
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">\
  <s:Body>\
    <login xmlns="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com">\
      <username>XXXXXXXXXXXXXX</username>\
      <password>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</password>\
    </login>\
  </s:Body>\
</s:Envelope>\n'

require(httr)
################################Posting the Login##############################################
result <- POST("https://test.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/48.0",body = body1,add_headers(.headers = c("Content-Type"="text/xml",'SOAPAction' = "https://test.salesforce.com")))

##############Parsing XML###############################################################
Output <- content(result)
doc = xmlTreeParse(Output, useInternal = TRUE)
top = xmlRoot(doc) 
xmlName(top)
names(top) 
names(top[[1]] [[1]] [[1]])
Session = top[[ 1 ]] [[1]] [[1]] [["sessionId"]] 
SessionId <- Session [1][1]$text
tok <- xmlToList(SessionId)  
Se <- paste("Bearer",tok,Sep="")
Se = trimws(Se)
Sever = top[[ 1 ]] [[1]] [[1]] [["serverUrl"]] 
SessionURL <- Sever [1][1]$text

################SF Query###########################################
SFQuery <- "SELECT Id,FirstName FROM Conatct limit 10"
SFQuery_Req <- GET(Pam,query = list(q=SFQuery),add_headers(Authorization=Se))
SFQuery_Con <- content(SFQuery_Req, as = 'text') %>% fromJSON()
SFQuery_Con_DF <- data.frame(SFQuery_Con$records)
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be many things, not all related to your code...

1. Your SOAP namespaces might be wrong. Maybe try with SoapUI / Postman / curl first and once you get these to work - check the code. Try with this version of the tags

   ```
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com">
       <soapenv:Body>
          <urn:login>
             <urn:username>usernamegoeshere</urn:username>
             <urn:password>passwordgoeshere</urn:password>
          </urn:login>
       </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
   ```
2. Log in to the SF org manually and check that user's login history at bottom of the page. Do you see your attempt at all? If not - are you sure you're connecting to right place (production vs sandbox)? Or maybe you have some proxy installed by your corporate IT and it just swallows the connections... If there's an entry in the login history - does it say invalid password? Too many failed login attempts? Security token needed?
3. It's possible admin disabled logging in from generic test.salesforce.com and you'll have to use what you see in Setup -> My Domain.
4. It's possible admin set your user for Single Sign-On (do you see normal SF login page or are redirected to some Active Directory stuff for example). If that's the case it'll be trickier to connect via API.
5. Maybe your user is not API-enabled, that'd be a Profile / Permission Set thing. Do you use system administrator account? Are there any login policies on the profile like access only from certain IPs or during certain login hours.

Comment: Thanks for the complete detailed explanation.  I am now able to successfully connect the SF. I have posted my complete code below for your reference.

Comment: Thx for coming back to the question and posting the solution! Everybody can benefit now.

Answer (score 0):

I maintain an R package called {salesforcer} that allows users to interact with 6 different Salesforce APIs (SOAP, REST, Bulk 1.0, Bulk 2.0, Metadata, Reports and Dashboards) to manage their Orgs. If one of these APIs suite your needs I would recommend using the package so that you do not need to write the code from scratch. Below is an example for how to connect using either OAuth 2.0, sometimes referred to as Single Sign-On, or with a username, password, and security token. Please visit the package's documentation site for additional detail and vignettes at: https://stevenmmortimer.github.io/salesforcer/

```r
# install.packages('salesforcer')
library(salesforcer)

# Using OAuth 2.0 authentication
sf_auth()

# Using Basic Username-Password authentication
sf_auth(username = "test@gmail.com", 
        password = "{PASSWORD_HERE}",
        security_token = "{SECURITY_TOKEN_HERE}")

# pull down information of person logged in
# it's a simple API call to get started 
# and confirm connection to the APIs
user_info <- sf_user_info()

sprintf("Organization Id: %s", user_info$organizationId)
#> [1] "Organization Id: 00D6A0000003dN3UAI"

sprintf("User Id: %s", user_info$userId)
#> [1] "User Id: 0056A000000MPRjQAO"
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately i could not able to install this package in my Org due to security limitation.